# Search your computer => "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search."

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, gdm

Switching from GDM (GNOME Display Manager) to LightDM on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS broke "Search your computer" functionality.

Fix found:

1. apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
2. apt remove gnome-shell
3. dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
4. reboot

Comment: What did you search for that resulted in the error? Do other searches for common programs work such as "Terminal" or "Firefox"?

Comment: Currently it doesn't find anything also the pre display already says that it doesnt find anything. No firefox neither terminal.

Comment: The steps to fix should be in an answer, not in the question post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

You will need to install unity. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service lightdm restart
```

The commands will ask for your password.